# Wordpress, doing AJAX request before admin submit a post

Tags: ajax, wordpress, forms, form-submit

I need to do some server-side checking, before admin may submit a post form:

```
$('body').on('submit', '#post', function(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent === undefined)
    {
        return true;
    }
    var thisForm = $(this);
    $.ajax('/check.php', $(this).serialize(), function(answer) {
        // if answer was ok...
        thisForm.submit();
    });
    return false;
});
```

actualy it works good, but in case when my post is "draft", I cant put it "public". Nothing changes, I guess some other JavaScript is affraing in the background.

BUT if I do a synchronous verion:

```
$('body').on('submit', '#post', function(e) {
    var error;
    $.ajax({type: 'POST', url: '/action.php', data: $(this).serialize(), async: false, success: function(answer) {
        // if answer was ok...
        error = true OR false;
    });
    return !error;
});
```

it all works GOOD! But you all know, one doesnt made synchronous ajax calls...